# How generate 200% image size and save with suffix @2x

Tags: plugins, images, retina

I need to know is it possible to generate 200%,200% image size and save with suffix @2x simply in WordPress? want to enable a simple retina ready theme.

Comment: Do you realize that scaling your original uploaded image file 200% is going to create a very low-quality image? The exact opposite of your intended purpose.

Comment: oh, i was thinking when it shrinks to 100% will display normal in retina displays. it seems i was wrong. however, isn't there a way to reduce image size by percentage not pixels? 

so can reduce big images to 50% and save as non retina